# Web Design: Line effect with block reveal style animation on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm currently trying to figure out how a current trend can be coded, I've seen this effect used quite often as seen here when using the navigation [www.bearideas.fr](http://bearideas.fr),

I've searched the web for some kind of explanation/tutorial as to how the lines and then ultimately the block reveal in each individual section but I can only find a plugin on typmanus which was a bit complicated for me to try and learn from and ultimately I couldn't get it working or understand.

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of any tutorials they have come across involving this effect or possibly explain a little how it works.

Sorry if this is the incorrect place to ask as I understand my question is a little bit vague but any type of help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Mike.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. Your question is highly off topic. The close comment is: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: PS: Design
        http://www.raphaelbeau.com/
        Development
        http://www.eric-huguenin.com

Comment: Have a look at this: https://tympanus.net/codrops/tag/page-transition/

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, will make sure I have a bit more information and have a crack at it next time before I next come on. Cheers, Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animated borders aren't actually `border` property. It's made out of `::before` and `::after` ([::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)) [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) "attached" to every navigation element, which are in short `display: block` with `width: 1px`, `height: 100%` and with some `background: #ccc`. These pseudo-elements are scaled down using [CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) using `transform: scaleY(0)`. On `:hover` ([:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)) it's scaled back to full size. Then it's animated using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions), precisely using `.35s cubic-bezier(.77,0,.175,1)` in this case.

It's actually not that hard, so don't let these articles scare you!

As for graying out navigation elements on hover, it may be some javascript logic.

Btw. you can inspect the page and see the implementation yourself. Press F12 and explore.

Comment: Hi Kamyl, thank you for your help, I've tried to upvote your answer but I don't think it will allow me yet, this gives me a better idea of how the elements work, just need to get a grasp of Javascript now. Cheers, Mike.